# Put Google Analytics code on a link?

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics, tracking

How do you put google analytics code on a link, for example a link on your page to a download file. Is there a way to call the analytics function from a link?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the click of the link using the `_trackPageview` function like so:

```
<a href="/wherever/file.pdf" onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/wherever/file.pdf')">Download Now</a>
```

The page view will be associated with whatever you pass to the `_trackPageview` function (/wherever/file.pdf in this case).

Google documentation is [here](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529&cbid=-1ltpcjzwkga4v&src=cb&lev=index).

Answer (score 0):

One option for you would be to create a download page that redirects to the file to be downloaded and includes a link manually download if it doesn't automatically start.

Google would be used to track the page rather than the file.

Comment: If redirect occurs faster than google is able to record the pageview there will be lost page views.